# Remove ether from PoA private network

Tags: gas-price, poa

I try to setup a private network containing three nodes (bootnode, sealer, transaction node with rpc) and PoA. So far so good.
The thing is I don't want to have any ether nor do I want to pay any gas for transactions since I only use the network to create contracts and interact with them (used it as a fancy database), so I don't need an actual currency.
I used geth to setup the three nodes and as long as I have ether in my system (accounts are funded and I pay the gasprice) all works fine. But as soon as I try to set the accepted gasprice for the sealer node via the `--miner.gasprice=0` and don't fund my accounts the transactions are not put to the blockchain anymore.
I'd be very happy if there is a solution to this.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You are still going to need gas as the internal unit of accounting, because otherwise a transaction can contain an infinite `for` loop that never terminates, crashing your nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. Alright so I thought if I set the gasPrice to 0 when deploying a contract and enable the sealer node to accept transactions with a gasPrice of 0 then they still should get sealed thus I would not need to have any ether on my accounts?